# Cannot generate rails command: bundle exec rspec spec/requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to start a second rails project, and for my firstone, rspec worked fine. I copied over the Gemfile to have the same gems, and I have the spec/requests directory in my project file. However, I get this error when I try to execute

C:\Sites\rails_projects\friendapp\app\views\static_pages>bundle exec rspec spec/
requests
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec
/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load': cannot load such file -- C:/Sites/rails_pr
ojects/friendapp/app/views/static_pages/spec/requests (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in`block in load_spec_files'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in`load_spec_files'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in`run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.1
1.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'

Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: did you run `bundle install` in your new project?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not executing bundle exec from the root of the app, but rather from app\views\static_pages:

```
C:\Sites\rails_projects\friendapp\app\views\static_pages>
```

The error message says that the file does not exist from that location (static_pages):

```
C:/Sites/rails_projects/friendapp/app/views/static_pages/spec/requests
```

Change to the root dir and try again

```
C:\Sites\rails_projects\friendapp\>bundle exec rspec spec/requests
```